# HTTP request failed, Status: 401, API Error: 239, User Message: Try Again

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am having Twitter Login along with Twitter Digits & Crashlytics. But the developers account for `Crashlytics` is different from `Digits` and `Twitter-Login`. 
This is my Application class

```
TwitterAuthConfig twitterConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(Config.getTwitterKey(), Config.getTwitterSecret());
Digits.Builder digitsBuilder = new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(twitterConfig), new Crashlytics(),
            new TwitterCore(twitterConfig), digitsBuilder.build());
```

So when I call the below code in app it returns 401

```
digitsAuthButton.setCallback(new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
                // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful for "
                        + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
                Log.d("Digits", "Sign in with Digits failure", exception);
            }
        });
```

Is this happening because of two different accounts ? or is there some other reason because my Twitter login is working but Digits isn't

Comment: for anyone facing this issue, I solved this way >> i was using twitter developer account's API KEY and SECRET KEY[that is wrong]. Instead you have to use these KEYs from Fabric's dashboard/developer console.  Thanks..!

Comment: But in that case it will behave as a different developer account. And one might loose all the data from the previous developer account even if both were registered with same email id.

Comment: you should use fabric developer account creds for digits API and twitter developer account for twitter login. Because, digits will authorize you only after matching your app_side creds with digits/fabric account's credentials.

Comment: The thing was I had created Twitter dev account earlier using twitter's developer's console and not Fabric's. But later I used Fabric's developer account to use Digit. This created mismatch because both keys are different even if you have same email id for both the accounts. Then I had to use Facebook's account kit

Comment: Are you solve this problem?

Comment: No. I shifted to Facebook Account Kit for using mobile otp authentication, because currently there is no way to port developer account made on Twitter to developer account on Fabric. But the keys internally collide for the two. So basically twitter dev account created on fabric is different from that on twitter dev console